# Visual Studio Cloud how to view errors and warnings that happen when my load test is running in the cloud?

Tags: visual-studio, testing, web-applications, performance-testing, load-testing

using Visual Studio cloud for performance testing application against SQL Server Database. How do I view errors and warnings that happen when my load test is running in the cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the cloud load test completes, down load the results and view them, including the error messages, in the results.

For more on how to download the results see step "5. When the test is done, download the report to view the results." within the "Run and analyze your load test" part of [this page](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-gb/docs/test/performance-testing/getting-started/getting-started-with-performance-testing).

Errors can be seen by clicking error count at the top of the results (the blue "2000 errors" in the next step of [the page](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-gb/docs/test/performance-testing/getting-started/getting-started-with-performance-testing). You can also access the errors via the "Tables" in the results (next to the orange-circled "Details" in the step 6 image), then select the "Errors" table. Click through to find the errors or results of interest. Expect the rightmost column, labelled "Details", of the results to have "Test log" entries for failing tests. Note that the default is that logs are only kept the first 200 failijng tests.